# tienda php, descontar stock en varios productos de una factura

Tags: php, html, sql, base-de-datos

Resulta que tengo facturación en php, al crear la factura me genera un `id_pago` donde se relaciona con varios productos que tiene su `id_producto`, necesito me colaboren con lo siguiente, al ejecutar `sql` que vaya a cada producto y descuento del stock que es `cantidad` y me lo deje con la cantidad actual. pero que ese comando se haga con cada producto que corresponde a esa factura `id_pago`. muestro mi código `sql`. necesito ayuda urgente ya que elabora el descuento pero solo del producto que elaboro el clic

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['aprovar'])) { 

             $x1=$_GET["codigo"];                    
            if( $x1=="" ){
                echo "<script> alert('".$x1."')</script>";
                echo "<br>";
             }
             else{

             $consulta="SELECT * FROM car where id_payment_id_car='".$x1."'";
             $bd->consulta($consulta);

                  while ($fila=$bd->mostrar_registros()) { 
                  $descontar= $fila->cantidacar;
                  $idService=$fila->id_service_car; 

                                     }
                 //$editar="UPDATE `service` SET `cantida` = `cantida`+'" . $totalactual . "' where `service`.`id_service` = '" . $id_salida . "'";
                 $editar="UPDATE `service` SET `cantida` = `cantida`-'$descontar' WHERE `service`.`id_service` = '$idService'";
                 $bd->consulta($editar);

            $sql3="UPDATE `payments` SET `state_payment` = 'aceptado' WHERE `payments`.`id_payments` = '".$x1."'";
            $bd->consulta($sql3);
                        //echo "Datos Editados Correctamente";
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <b>Bien!</b> Se Aprovo Correctamente... </div>';
                }
    }
?>
```

Este es el botón de ejecución.

```
<a class="dt-button buttons-pdf buttons-html5 btn blue btn-outline " data-toggle="modal" href="?admin=procesando&aprovar&codigo=<?php echo $id ?>"   title="Pago revisado aprovar"   onclick='if(confirmAprov() == false){return false;}' ><i class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i></a>
```

Comment: No trabajo con php, pero supongo que dentro de un while deberías hacer el descuento producto por producto, yo sólo veo un while donde asignas algún valor a $descontar y a $idService...

Comment: umm si claro pero necesitaba continuar con este hilo